# Does Being Paid Salary Mean My Days Should Be Longer?

Tags: management, salary, united-states, time-management, hours

I was recently moved from hourly pay to salary pay so I'm used to leaving work on time. Now that I'm salary though I keep getting remarks from management that seem point at I should be staying at work longer than what I signed up for or working longer hours.

Even though I truly know this is not the case, do employers expect people to work longer being paid salary?

Comment: The answer to this question is "it depends." Some companies and some managers have dramatically different expectations. Additionally, some positions simply have expectations for increased responsibility and worktime. There's really not an answer to this question.

Comment: @enderland Salary vs hourly is a legal classification, so its not quite just an it depends answer.  There are restrictions for employers.

Comment: @Andy there are a ton of laws and regulations, which vary by country, and contractual obligations. Different job classifications also have different legal responsibilities which again vary by country. Which also means, "it depends."

Comment: It sounds like in your case, probably it is a "yes".  But bottom line: are you deliverables being met?

Comment: Most employers I've known do think so. That being said, I've never agreed.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I meant that it's probably illegal to force someone to work overtime even on salary.

Comment: Hourly pay in most cases means that employer is not sure that they have enough work and think that salary employee will have to be idle frequently (i.e. they will pay more than necessary). When they see that there is enough work, they prefer to pay salary.

Answer (score 4):

Salary means you are paid a fixed amount to accomplish a goal.  In theory you should be fine to work only 30 hours is that's all you need to accomplish goals, or sometimes you need to work more if that's what is required.  In practice though you may be expected to handle a work load where you have to put in more time.  Sometimes employers try to incorrectly classify employees as salary to avoid overtime pay (this is illegal).  Employers must be careful though because if their may focus is tracking how many hours you're working it may force them back to hourly status.

Comment: The salary goal can also be simply to be there for certain periods of times. There are lots of shift-based, salary employees in tech jobs.

Comment: Sometimes the goal you're paid for is "work x number of hours".